# Return MongoDB query result as variable instead of to console

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, return-value, native-code

In a javascript file named `db_to_var.js` I have the following function that succesfully prints the array returned by a query to database `test_db`, to `console.log()` . (E.g. a database called `cars` which have a key `name` describes the brandname, e.g. `toyota, hyunday,volvo`.). The method is called with: `console.log("listCars function call="+listCars());` and contains:

```
function listCars() { 
    car_and_name_grandparent = MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("testdb");

        car_and_name_parent = dbo.collection("cars").find({}, { projection: { _id: 0, name: 1} }).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            car_and_name = result;
            db.close();

            console.log("car_and_name="+car_and_name);
            return car_and_name;
        });

        return car_and_name_parent;
    });

    return car_and_name_grandparent;
};
```

However, `car_and_name_parent` remain undefined because the `car_and_name`, which is filled correctly is not actually returned to the `car_and_name_parent`. This led me to investigate, and I looked into:

1. [The documentation of `.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/), which is not supposed to take an argument in the first place. Hence I inspected what `dbo.collection("cars").find({}, { projection: { _id: 0, name: 1} }).toArray()` actually returns, which is an `[object Promise]`.

   1.a One can't evaluate a `Promise` directly but has to use `then`, `await` or `async`.

   1.b I am able to convert the `Promise` into `function then() { [native code] }`
   using `.then` but I have not found how to further evaluate this
   expression to retrieve the list out of "`[native code]`". The
   `await` returns error saying `SyntaxError: await is only valid in
   async function`, whereas `async car_and_name.then` returns error
   `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.
2. I also tried passing a global variable named `carNames` into the functions, and to assign it value `car_and_name`, but I am currently not able to succesfully pass the global variable to inside the `.toArray(..)` as `console.log(carNames);` is undefined when I do that, in that position.

How can I return the `car_and_name` variable to a variable outside the function `listCars()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with async await.

```
async function listCars() {
    let db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    let dbo = db.db("testdb");
    return await dbo.collection("cars").find({}, { projection: { _id: 0, name: 1} }).toArray()
}

listCars().then(cars => {
    console.log(cars); //You will get your results here
})
```

The mongoDB queries in nodejs like the one above are asynchronous so you cannot get the return value in a variable directly. You either have to use a callback function or `.then()` to use promises like in the example above.

The toArray() function you are using is a MongoDB method, the one you mentioned in your question is a jQuery one. This is the correct documentation for your reference -> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, especially noting I referred to the wrong language documentation. My intention was to call/retrieve the `var globalVar` from another file `app.js` but I will rework the implementation of that call/retrieval to work with your given solutions as it appears not possible to get the data as a global variable. Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Your method is making an asynchronous call which is instantly executed as a Promise before the value you're looking for is retrieved.

I'd recommend wrapping your method in a promise.

```
function listCars() { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        var dbo = db.db("testdb");

        dbo.collection("cars").find({}, { projection: { _id: 0, name: 1} }).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            db.close();
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
  })
};
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
listCars()
    .then(carNames => {
        // Use your variable here.
    })
    .catch(err => throw err);
```

You can also use listCars as a helper method in an async method like so.

```
const carWork = async function() {
    try {
       const carNames = await listCars();
       // ....
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your examples and explanation. It appears I should not want a separate variable with a list of car names. Since also your answer, has the variable inside a lambda function which takes input `carnames` and returns nothing,  inside property `then` of function `listCars`. It makes me wonder whether it is even possible/desirable to get the content of the query as a global variable, is it? Reading @twjs answer, it seems not possible/desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use async/await. But you didn't used it right way. You got syntax error that says you can use await only in async function. So you can write your code like this,

```
async function listCars() { 
 try{
    db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    var dbo = db.db("testdb");
    car_and_name_parent = await dbo.collection("cars").find({}, { 
      projection: { _id: 0, name: 1} }).toArray();
   return car_and_name_parent
}catch(err){
  throw err;
 }
};
```

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response, I tried to call it with `var globalVar = listCars();` and `var globalVar = eval(listCars());` which returns: `Promise { <pending> }`. Perhaps you could extend your example with how to use it?

Comment: Usage: var globalVar = await listCars(); This directly assigns car name list to globalVar.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it throws: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. Even though, I agree with you that `listCars()` definitely looks like an async function. (For completeness: I copy pased both your answer and comment literally, 3 times to make sure I did not make a copy paste error.)

Comment: As I already mentioned that await can only be used inside of async method so to call listCars from any async block. Otherwise you can use it with promise,
listCars().then((list) => {
 var globalVar = list;
}).catch(err){
  // handle error.  
}